# Hide and Show Actionbar elements disappeared

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-actionbar, hide

I need hide ActionBar at one precise moment hide the ActionBar and place the app in fullscreen, so hide the view of the elements like text view. The problem is that when I go back to normal mode the textview is behind the ActionBar.

Does anyone have any idea how can I fix this?

```
    int uiOptions;
    mView = this.getWindow().getDecorView();
    TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textName);

    if (enabled) {
        text.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
        mView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 1000);

    } else {
        text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE;
        mView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
        getSupportActionBar().show();
        customHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerThread);
        if (mMenu != null) {
            mMenu.setTitle(R.string.menu_start);
        }
        mView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    }
```

Comment: Just put the element to stay visible after the ActionBar is visible and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Just put the element to stay visible after the ActionBar is visible and it worked!